# Cordova whitelisting allow-navigation vs access origin

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

What is the difference between allow-navigation and access origin in cordova whitelisting ?
This may seem to be easy but did not got proper info. i got in the web.
Help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

**allow-navigation:** 
URLs the WebView itself can be navigated to. By default, navigations only to file:// URLs, are allowed.

**access origin:** 
Controls which network requests (images, XHRs, etc) are allowed to be made (via cordova native hooks).

Comment: Thanks. So, if my server url is https://mypage.com, then i specify <access origin="https://mypage.com/*"> correct ? but even i have <access origin="https://google.com/*"> it works ! ..please help .. but my allow-navigation is *

Comment: This is an ionic application